# Multi Curl Usage when number of requests is dynamic

Tags: php, mysql, curl

I have a database setup and all it does is give me at most 10 URL's. I need to post data to those 10 URL's when the page is loaded. This means the script to send message hits "send.php?message=Foo". and it post's 'foo' to the pages in the database. There is no way around this. But I need to be able to do it. Right now I am trying to use regular curl requests in a *while* loop but that only posts to the first URL. How do I use the CURL multi functions to do this:

```
 $query = 'SELECT * FROM `chat` LIMIT 0, 20;'; 
$result = mysql_query($query);
    $init = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
 $URL = $row['url'];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"$URL");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it only posts to the first URL? Try adding some debugging statements. Check if you're hitting a timeout in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

What about timeouts? Look at the example here https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php. Start a multi handle before while, create curl handles in while and add those handles to multi handle method, then after while execute the curl call and close the handle, do check for errors/exceptions thrown by curl, example, a url may time out and so on.